# ASP.NET Core JSON param always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to pass a serialized model from ajax to my controller, but I can't seem to get anything but null to come across. Rather than spend a lot of time talking, I am just going to show code.

The queryDetails is properly formatting the object into { name: val } format, but it is not coming across into the controller.

**Summary.cshtml Javascript Code**

top of file declaration:

```
var QueryData = ViewData["QueryData"] as QueryModel;
```

....

in Js code:

```
var queryDetails =  @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@QueryData));

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/SummaryRefresh',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { queryDetails },
    success: function () {
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SummaryRefresh([FromBody] QueryModel queryDetails)
{
    // STACKOVERFLOW NOTE: function is hit, but queryDetails is null
    if (queryDetails != null)
    {
        ViewData["QueryData"] = queryDetails;
        return View("Summary");
    }
    else 
        return BadRequest("Error refreshing view");
}
```

**Startup.cs**

...

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
       name: "SummaryRefresh",
       pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=SummaryRefresh}/{queryDetails?}");
```

...

**QueryModel.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Holds the query data enetered by user
/// </summary>
public class QueryModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Different ways to view summary mode
    /// </summary>
    public enum SummaryDisplayMode
    {
        Full,
        Quick
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current summary view mode
    /// </summary>
    private SummaryDisplayMode displayMode = SummaryDisplayMode.Full;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get/Set display mode
    /// </summary>
    public SummaryDisplayMode DisplayMode { get => displayMode; set => displayMode = value; }

    /// <summary>
    ///  PO Name filter
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Product Owner", Prompt = "Name")]
    public string POName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Delivery Order Filter
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Delivery Order", Prompt = "Example: [removed]")]
    public string DeliveryOrder { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Port Number filter
    /// </summary>
    [RegularExpression(@"^PORT-+([0-9]{3}|[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{5})$", ErrorMessage = "[removed]")]
    [Display(Name = "[removed]")]
    public string PortNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Epic Type filter
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Epic Type")]
    public string EpicType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Program Increment Filter
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Program Increment", Prompt = "Example: 20D")]
    public string ProgramIncrement { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether or not to show resolved capabilities
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Show Resolved Ports")]
    public bool ShowResolved { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether or not to show backlogs
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Show Backlogs")]
    public bool ShowBacklogs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public QueryModel()
    {
        POName = "";
        PortNumber = "";
        DeliveryOrder = "";
        EpicType = "NA";
        ShowResolved = true;
        ShowBacklogs = false;
    }
}
```

Debugged paylod:

> displayMode=0&poName=jkeller&deliveryOrder=&portNumber=&epicType=NA&programIncrement=&showResolved=true&showBacklogs=false

Comment: Could you post QueryModel and QueryData classes pls?

Comment: You might want to observe network trace to see what exact json is being posted to server from ajax

Comment: QueryData is just a copy of the model instance (var QueryData = ViewData["QueryData"] as QueryModel;)

Comment: and where is a QueryModel then?

Comment: @Serge I had already updated the question when I replied, sorry. Its up there

Comment: I tested posting your model to your controller with Postman, success so far. Hence I guess there are issues in the JS code.

Comment: @RoarS. is it possible the problem is the line converting the model object to json?

Comment: My primary suspect is this line: `data: { queryDetails },` , I guess it should be `data: queryDetails,`

Comment: @RoarS. I made that change but not seeing any difference in controller. I debugged networking and this is what I see in the payload: "displayMode=0&poName=namehere&deliveryOrder=&portNumber=&epicType=NA&programIncrement=&showResolved=true&showBacklogs=false"   is that what should be expected?

Comment: when i debug, the queryDetails variable = "{"displayMode":0,"poName":"jkeller","deliveryOrder":null,"portNumber":null,"epicType":"NA","programIncrement":null,"showResolved":true,"showBacklogs":false};"

Comment: Found the issue, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution seems to be to replace

```
data: { queryDetails },
```

with

```
data: JSON.stringify(queryDetails),
```

Reason is that this line creates an object, not JSON

```
var queryDetails =  @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@QueryData));
```

Hence the object needs to be converted to JSON before performing the POST.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much for sticking with me on this one. Appreciate your help!

Comment: My pleasure @JeremyK. Always satisfying to solve small mysteries :-)

Answer (score 0):

This was tested in Visual Studio, and it is working

```
[Route("~/Home/SummaryRefresh")]
public IActionResult SummaryRefresh( QueryModel queryDetails)
```

ajax should be like this

```
var queryDetails =  @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@QueryData));

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/SummaryRefresh',
    data: { queryDetails:queryDetails },
    success: function (result) {
     
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Serge: I believe OP specified that controller method is hit.

Comment: Yes, my method is hit, but the param is always null

Comment: @JeremyK I can't  help you if I can't see queryDetails json object. Please post it. I don' t like to advise using a guess.

Comment: "Since a PO refuses to post jqueryDetails json object" I updated the question to include it...

Comment: @JeremyK Thanks, But I can't see it

Comment: @JeremyK Thanks for update, I updated my answer too. Pls try it and let me know.